Secondary character with prosopagnosia
For some reason, a specific scene from some book (English, probably written 1990-2015, very probably either published by Baen, or written by an author that Baen publishes) popped into my head, and I can't remember what book it's from.
Specifically, it involves a minor character with prosopagnosia (pretty sure the technical name is given in the text). This character, who we'll call Dan, is a male. He is approached by two other characters we'll call Anne and Barb. One or both is a/the "main" character, but I don't recall which is which. Anne, who knows Dan from way back, is definitely female, but I'm less certain about the other.
I specifically remember Anne giving some "totem" to Barb so Dan can recognize her; as I recall, it was a small flower or flower pin. Dan, as I recall, wears pink gloves and makes a comment at some point about how almost no one else wears such things (thus they are fairly reliable to identify him to himself). I might have the color or object wrong, but I am confident about him wearing something very unusual, and making a comment about it.
As I recall, the pair went to Dan because he has an unusual ability that relates to finding things. The ability may or may not be supernatural, but as I recall there were supernatural elements in the story universe (vampires and the like, I want to say), although this may not have been the primary "sci-fi" element of the story.
Does anyone recognize this?

Do Ann, Barb and Dan have a friend called Charlie?

This is Invasion: Book One of the Secret World Chronicle by Mercedes Lackey.

“You keep staring at them. Did you mean to wear the white ones?”
He held up his gloved hands. “Ah. No, it’s a mental trick. I’m usually the only person in the room with pink gloves, thus I know these hands are mine and not someone else’s.”
“Of course they’re yours. You operate them, you receive tactile information from them, right?”
“Sometimes it’s not enough,” Jack Point said in a quiet voice.
Ramona blew air out her lips. “Sorry. I guess I forget how acute your condition is. You can’t even recognize yourself?”
He shook his head.
“So you’ve never really seen your own face?”
“I was normal until I was twelve. That’s the last time I saw myself.”  He smiled. “But among neuroscientists, I’m a rock star, so it’s not so bad. The most acute case of prosopagnosia in history. I go right off the charts.” He chuckled. “Some of them are convinced vivisecting my brain will reveal the nature of consciousness itself. I’ve lost count of the MRIs I’ve been subjected to.”



Ah, I had a suspicion, but wasn't looking forward to reading the whole series to find out! (Especially as I was thinking it wasn't in the first book...) IIRC, Vix knows some vampires and/or werewolves (I want to say one of her parents is a werewolf?), but the main "sci-fi" element is of course the "metahumans" who aren't, strictly speaking, supernatural.

@Matthew - I just used Google Books to look up ("Baen" and "prosopagnosia") and this was the first match.

Really? Sigh, I tried regular Google search with no luck; apparently that's really as useless as I hear, these days...

@Matthew - Different searches do different things. If you want to search for text inside a book then the best place to do it is Google Books, not the main search bar
